# Maintain a nice, informative documentation by hooking into the APT system?

Tags: linux, apt

Ideally I would like something which:

- Allowed me to write a *reason* for installation of a package or a set of packages.
- Kept track of all changes the installed package made to my system. I would like to see /etc file modifications, user and group changes and file changes overall. And anything important I forgot. :-)
- Allowed me to write a *reason* for removing a package or a set of packages.
- Allowed me to modify the reasons I gave at a later time. I might have installed a package to begin with just because I wanted to check it out. Then I might find it really useful and have a good reason for keeping it. As the reasons are for documentation and not a diary I'd like to change the original reason "Just testing it out" into "Installed as it offers services x,y,z using a minimal and fast implementation".
- Allowed me to (manually) include the manual steps I needed to perform. Like change that files' contents, and that ones permissions, remove that file & create that file. Basically log commands I perform together with some documentation comments. And tie them to the packages I installed/removed which caused these manual steps to be necessary.
- I could get output from which basically is a description of how to duplicate my system on a freshly installed machine. This means that only the installed/removed packages that differs from the fresh install are shown with their descriptions (still in sequental order as packages may depend upon each other).

**Questions**

- Does it sound like a good system for documentation? Why? Why not? What can be improved?
- Is there something like this out there already?
- Is it possible to hook into the APT system to gain the necessary level of control to create something like this? Any tips on how?
- Do you have any suggestions on how to implement something like this?

If something like this is not out there already, I might have a try at creating something myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of what you are doing seems like it would be covered by using a combination of a configuration management system (like [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/)) and a change control system (like subversion).

As you add, remove, modify packages, you do them through the puppet system; you then check your configuration changes in, and log what changed and why.

This lets you not only reproduce a system, but also lets you reproduce it at any point in time. You also get control over more than just the package files; you can control all the config files in your system.

Comment: Completely agreed. Puppet and svn will do exactly what Kent wants.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm a fan of Puppet myself (well, technically, I love the idea of Puppet and loathe the implementation, but that's a whole other story), and would recommend that in general, you could produce more-or-less what you want with some scripts -- apt is powerful enough to do that.  Also, the `etckeeper` package does the "config change tracking" bit for you, and would provide an example of how to hook into apt to do what you want.

I use `etckeeper` on my workstation just to have an idea of what changed and when, but I would not *ever* consider it as a replacement for a real configuration management system on production systems.  It just doesn't (can't!) keep track of enough system state to make it a viable alternative.